# Update/ Insert custom table after creating/ updating new post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way to update a couple of mySQL tables when I create a new post or edit an existing post.

For example, I have a custom post type called 'television'. I have a custom table called tvoffers which stores offers for a particular television.

So, if I am writing a post on say Sony Bravia 32" LCD, I can also enter information in the TV offers such as :

```
offer_id   post_id  Offer_name   Offer_code    Offer_link   Price
```

?

Is this possible to do? Any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a Wordpress [`hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks). In this case, you should apply an action hook to the [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action (or any other action hooks that you think would be a better match; lots of them exist):

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_database_with_info' );

function update_database_with_info( $post_id ) {
    // Now do something with the post
}
```

This code should be added to your `functions.php` file, located in your themes directory.

Note that an updated page also triggers `save_post`, so you might want to take this into account in your function.